# Populate a Custom XML Structure From a MySQL Table Row-By-Bow

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml

I have this custom tag structure:

```
<warehouse>

    <frontbay>

    </frontbay>

    <bayrow>

        <bay>

        </bay>

        <bay>

        </bay>

        <bay>

        </bay>

        <bay>

        </bay>

        <bay>

        </bay>

        <bay>

        </bay>

     </bayrow>  

     <aisle>

     </aisle>       

     <bayrow>

           ...more bays...

     </bayrow>

     <aisle>

     </aisle>

    </warehouse>
```

What is the best way to make the `<bay>`s inside the `<bayrow>`s in to a list, starting from the first one and catching all to the last one, to pass data from a `MySQL` database?

- The bay, and its corresponding row on the MySQL table, will **always** stay the same.
- Essentially it should be directly linked to my primary, auto-incrementing Bay. So bay 1 in the elements is the first row of the 'BayNumber' column.
- If, at a later date, I wanted to make BayNumber:1 start at a different element - not necessarily the first one in the structure, which method would be best of the following?

With consideration to the above as well as for the purpose of speed, would it be best to:

1. Give each bay its own `ID`?
2. Write code pointing to its place on the MySQL table directly inside each bay?
3. Write a script to compile a list of the bays, and pass the table rows in one by one to each element in the list?

   - And if a script, would you recommend using JS or PHP to get the list? (I'm new to PHP, but I know some Javascript & jQuery)

I could be completely missing a better method to do this, such as placing a reference to the elements in to the MySQL table or something like that, so please advise me on the best course of action for **Populating a Custom XML Structure From a MySQL Table Row-By-Bow**.

Comment: Your goal is unclear. If the data changes in the database, just regenerate your XML data, or am I missing something?

Comment: @YaK The XML is a static template, it's not dependant on what's in the MySQL, those bays will always be in the same place but they won't always have something in them, so there's no point dynamically generating the XML every time, is there?

Comment: I think you would spend more (CPU) time loading the XML file, finding a `<bay>`, inserting data, than if you just generated the whole file. And even if not, the time wasted would be really insignificant. Really, you should rebuild the entire file. If the other immutable parts of the XML file are relatively large, just rebuild the whole `<bayrow>` section. But do not bother "moving around" tags. It is not worth it, IMHO, unless the final XML file is *huge* (several megabytes), and only a very small part of it is mutable.

Comment: @YaK It'll be minimum 900, maximum 2500 bays

Comment: That's a good suggestion by YaK to rebuild the entire file. For example if you have an error in your generation code, rebuilding the whole file will make the process more manageable so you can better reproduce and bug fix here. The XML is only the serialization of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be overthinking this problem. Generating an XML file with 2500 tags shouldn't take that long, unless their contents are really large.

I would try with the naive approach fist: generate the whole file on each request and keep an eye on the server load. Maybe cache the result and purge the cache when the database changes.

But if you really want to take this route, I would definitely add an `id` attribute to each `<bay>` tag, matching the primary key of your `bay` entity in the database.